# Communicating between Java <-> Java/C#/Objective-C

Tags: c#, java, android, ios, mobile

What is the best way to communicate between Java <-> Java/C#/Objective-C?

We have Java as server component and Andorid, Windows Phone, iOS as client. Currently we are using json as communication medium, we uses library for de/serialization and they are fine. speed is ok. easy to debug. But whenever we add a new object or a new field to an existing object, it will take some effort to update the mapping and make changes in all platform.

We have been looking into protobuf and thrift, protobuf looks good but looks like no official support to objective-c and it's binary? hard to debug? thrift on the other hand doesn't support polymorphism which we do need that.

What is the best strategy for this? Is there any existing technology that I can leverage? How is everyone doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which library you are using to de/serialize? I thought in JSON communication, new changes are  easily adaptable

Comment: we use jackson in java to de/serialize. we can reuse the object easily in android. but in C# and Objective-C we have to add a new field or object everytime server adds one.

Comment: I think XML or JSON are reasonable choices.

Comment: But the libraries used and/or your schema  should allow compatible changes without redeployment of client. Adding a field should not break the client.

Answer (score 0):

in objective-c, you can use **JSONKit**, it is very simple

use like this:

NSDictionary *dic = [recieveStr objectFromJSONString];

NSString *str = [arr JSONString];

Comment: I think the question is *`But whenever we add a new object or a new field to an existing object, it will take some effort to update the mapping and make changes in all platform`*

Comment: "add a new object or a new field to an existing object" do not affect client, i think, if client need not to use the added new field.